# How merge yaml in podTemplate?

Tags: kubernetes, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have the following code in groovy:

```
void call(Closure closure) {
    pod_template_maven_image = ...
    pod_template_maven_m2 = ...
    pod_template_nodejs_image = ...
    pod_template_sonar_image = ...
    toleration_condition = true

    def yaml_config = ""
    if(toleration_condition){
        yaml_config = """
        spec:
          tolerations:
          - key: "my_toleration"
            operator: "Equal"
            value: "value1"
            effect: "NoSchedule"
        """
    }

    podTemplate(containers: ..., 
    volumes: ..., 
    etc..., 
    yaml: yaml_config, 
    yamlMergeStrategy: merge()) {
        node(POD_LABEL) {
            closure()
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, when I run the job in jenking nothing happens, the pod is created whitout error. But the yaml is not added in pod.

We want to add the toleration (yaml_config) in podTemplate depending of toleration_condition value.

I'm new in this area and don't now if is possible.
Its is? Whats the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Tip: I see you use the Kubernetes plugin. Have you seen the section of [inheritance](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-inheritance)? Using the declarative pipeline syntax, with `inheritFrom`, might provide a much cleaner way to achieve the wanted results. Here we also keep the `yamlMergeStrategy` as default (`override()`).*

I have seen that the indents of the "delta yaml" (`yaml_config`), provided to `yaml:`, influences the final outcome (trailing and starting newlines could also have impact). So I would recommend testing with a `yaml_config` like:

```
    yaml_config = """
spec:
  tolerations:
  - key: "my_toleration"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "value1"
    effect: "NoSchedule" """
```